# Unix environment — extract date strings and compare

Tags: string, date, variables, unix, compare

Could anyone help me with a UNIX script that extracts the date from the last line of a file, compares it to current date, and if date from file is with 1 hour delay between current date, echo YES?

File.txt

```
18:48:43 iLIKEtoMOVEitMoveIT
18:58:43 iLIKEtoMOVEitMoveIT
19:22:43 iLIKEtoMOVEitMoveIT
clear line
```

So far I figured out how to get the last line which has the time:

```
tail -n 2 File.txt | head c-8
```

Output = 19:22:43
And how to store the current date as only time in a variable:

```
TheCurrentDate="date +"%T""
```

How to compare those 2 HH:MM:SS and calculate if one hour has passed between them, then echo"YES".  All put in script.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATE=$(tail -n 2 File.txt | cut -c 1-8 | head -n 1)
FROM_FILE=$(date -d "$DATE" +%s)
NOW=$(date +%s)
DIFFERENCE=$((NOW - FROM_FILE))

if [ $DIFFERENCE -le 3600 ]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

The idea is to convert the timestamp to seconds since epoch (`+%s`) using `date`. Then you just compare numbers.

*EDIT*

Your `File.txt` should does seem like a log file, where the logging program doesn't bother to prepend the date. As @Jonathan Leffler pointed out, `NOW` could be `00:15` and `FROM_FILE` could be `23:45`.

In this case, `date` would interpret `FROM_FILE` as being the end of today, rather than the end of yesterday. This can be fixed ad-hoc:

```
DATE=$(tail -n 2 File.txt | cut -c 1-8 | head -n 1)
FROM_FILE=$(date -d "$DATE" +%s)
NOW=$(date +%s)

if [ $FROM_FILE -gt $NOW ]; then
    # it's not really in the future, it's from yesterday
    FROM_FILE=$((FROM_FILE - 24 * 3600))
fi

DIFFERENCE=$((NOW - FROM_FILE))

if [ $DIFFERENCE -le 3600 ]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

Comment: What happens if one time is 23:45 and the next is 00:15?  Is that within an hour or not?  It depends in large part on whether the information is in time sequence or not.  It usually is,  and therefore those times are probably half an hour apart.  But that's something the OP should tell us.  It's also a compelling reason for always recording the date as well as the time.

Comment: Hi, as you say 23:45 - 00:15 is still preceived as being in the hour limit.
That is why the log file writes "from time to time - nobody knows exactly when".and only as time and not full date.

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving it root ! 

Much appreciated <3